# Is it possible to access categories from an outside root category?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, category

I have a root category set up for all the products. What I am trying to do is set up what I call a meta category. This category would be used for things like holiday themes, gifts for him, etc.

What I did was created a root category called "Meta Categories" and I have subcategories under it. The issue I am running into is when I show the category image and link to it on the front page, I'm taken to a 404 page. I noticed the URLs look different from other category URLs also, `domain.com/catalog/category/view/s/independence-day/id/31/`

Is this possible to do? If so, how do I do it? If not, what would you suggest to complete this? I'm trying to make the administration of the store as easy as possible and currently just list all the subcategories and it would make it harder to manage the store if the categories have to manually exclude or include certain categories to render the store menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get an SEO URL because a URL rewrite doesn't exist for that category for your store.

Using categories for taxonomy isn't ideal. Instead you should add attributes to products to define the type, then make a module which filters the collection by that type.